# jQuery Form submit event does not fire on submit button

Tags: jquery, jsp

The following does not work: on clicking my Submit button in the JSP, I do not see any alerts.

I added both types of the Submit event, none of them fires. Maybe I'm not including some relevant jQuery JS, in addition to 3.1.1.min and UI? I do get the Startup `document.ready()` alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Does Not Work
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    alert('TEST');
  });

// Does Not Work
$('#form').submit(function() {
    alert('In form submit');
    return false;
});

    // This is OK
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#wait").hide();
        alert('Startup');
    });
</script>
```

JSP (using some Struts tags, `styleId` translate to `id` in HTML):

```
<html:form styleId="form" action="/generate">

<table class=menu_2 cellSpacing="4" cellPadding="4" border="0">
        <TBODY>
        <tr valign="bottom">
                <td>
                <label class="formLabel" for="idTypeG">Number</label><br/>
                <html:text property="number" maxlength="50" title="Enter Number"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td COLSPAN=4>
                <html:submit styleClass="clsFormBtn" value="Generate"/>&nbsp; 

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</Table>

<div id="wait">
    PLEASE WAIT...
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: You have to put the event listeners in the DOM ready function. The form element is not present at runtime so no event listeners will be bound.

Comment: I don't see any element with `id="form"` in your html... `$('#form').submit` is looking for element with `id="form"`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the validate interceptor?